# Multiple Administrator of Windows Azure account

Tags: azure

I have read that you can have Co-Administrator for Windows Azure subscription but can I have multiple Administrators for the same account? I need multiple administrator so that they can also have subscription if needed

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'account'? generally speaking, outside an enterprise account, one has a subscription and one or more windows accounts who are administrators of it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have more than one user to be able to create subscriptions in an enterprise account?

Comment: Yes!! I want user to create subscriptions in an enterprise account

Comment: 2016, still I'm looking for a solution to this. OP did you solve it?

Comment: @deepesh were you able to solve the problem? Got the same.

Answer (score 10):

In the Azure management console (http://manage.windowsazure.com), click "Subscriptions" at the top of the page and then hit "Manage Administrators" in the drop-down menu:

[image: Manage Administrators]

This will allow you to add/edit/remove one or more administrators to your subscriptions.

Comment: This will create co-administrator but I want another user to have same privileges as main adminsitrator

Comment: Co-admins can do everything an admin can do. What privileges, specifically, have you noticed not being there?

Comment: Co-admin can not see billing information, I want user to see billing information as well

Comment: What, if any, is the maximum number of co-administrators that can be added?

Comment: 200 is the maximun co-administrator that you can add to a subscription @bytefire

Comment: Subscriptions is no longer at the top of the page, it's now in the Settings tab on the left. Subscription filter appears at the top if you have more than one subscription (which most of us don't).

Comment: I have the same problem, the boss made the account and get access to the billing information but he doesn't know anything about azure and what each item means. I can only find in the billing information what we spend on what service (so i need to use his email/login and he does not like that very much), what makes it difficult to optimize services we use and how much we pay for it.

Comment: @EwaldBos I'm not sure what you want to do? Do you want to access the services (tech) or the account (billing) site using your own login? Or are you trying to figure out how much you're going to spend per month? If you want the latter, take a look at the Azure pricing calculator: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Answer (score 3):

You can have 1 Account Administrator and 1 Service Administrator, but you can have 200 Co-Administrators per subscription.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh531793.aspx#BKMK_HowToAccess

Comment: The OP's already said (in a comment) he needs more than a co-administrator. The question states he knows about co-administrators

Comment: This actually answers OP's question: No, you can't have more than one Admin that can see the billing information. [See also](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator/), especially Q&A at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of the portal you have to follow the path bellow:

Left navigation panel > More services > Subscriptions > Select your subscription > IAM (Access Control) > Add

Comment: For more information on this process see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't have multiple Azure Account Administrators.