# How can i make the azure subscription shared to multiple users

Tags: azure

Please i want to add a multiple users to the same Windows Azure subscriptions, i tried to users to the same default Azure Active Directory but when i tried to login with this account an issue was happened is that this user does not have any subscription.

Comment: Are you trying to add co-administrators?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14913114/1384539

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio - good catch. Since I believe the min rep needed for close-votes is 3000 (which you're not quite at), I went ahead and submitted a close vote, as duplicate to the question you referenced. Of course, that assumes the OP is actually wanting to add co-admins, vs. something else with Active Directory...

Comment: i do not need to add co-administrator, actually i need to add my employees to the same subscription